# PHP - Why use move_uploaded_file and not rename?

Tags: php, file-upload

In the manual I can see it says something about security reasons, but I didn't quite understand what is the problematic situation.

> This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is
>   a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST
>   upload mechanism). If the file is valid, it will be moved to the
>   filename given by destination.
>
> This sort of check is especially important if there is any chance that
>   anything done with uploaded files could reveal their contents to the
>   user, or even to other users on the same system.

So it makes sure it was uploaded via PHP, but if it will not check that, what could happen? what information could be revealed, and how?

Can someone explain this? An example will be great.

Comment: The file content itself and the file name, obviously. Imagine php allowing an upload right into a `/img` folder which is published via http. The image would be available _before_ php can further process it, protect it, validate its content and name, rename it.

Comment: @arkascha But that's not my question. You can validate all necessary things, and then use `rename` and not `move_uploaded_file`.

Comment: But the file would already be in the same physical location if you'd only rename it. With all potential security implications. Note: that is not necessarily insecure. But it is probably that some people will implement insecure setups. That is why another solution was chosen. And, btw, why does it matter?

Comment: @arkascha What do you mean? it doesn't matter if you use `rename` or `move_uploaded_file`, the file will be uploaded to the same temp folder. (rename can also move files across drives). And it matters becuase I wanted to know what exactly security holes it can cause.

Comment: Ah, ok, indeed I originally understood your question in another way.

Comment: If this is _only_ about why a specific function is used as opposed to php's generic `rename()` fucntion, then I _assume_ that the specific function makes an additional validation: if the file to be moved/renamed actually _is_  one uploaded in the current request. But as said: I only assume that. You'd have to take a look into the implementation to be certain.

Answer (score 2):

A PHP script will likely move files around whose name is determined at runtime (the name of a temporary file that has just been uploaded). The check is meant to ensure that poorly-written scripts don't expose system files, or files containing authentication secrets.

Suppose I write a script that lets you upload an image to my server, enhance it by embedding some super-cute cat gifs that I provide, and download it again. To keep track of which image you are working on, I embed the file name in the request URLs for my edit buttons:

```
http://example.com/add-kitty.php?img=ato3508.png&add=kitty31.gif
```

Or maybe I embed the same information in a cookie or POST data, wrongly thinking that this makes it more secure. Then some moderately enterprising script kiddie comes by and tries this (or the POST/cookie equivalent):

```
http://example.com/add-kitty.php?img=$2Fetc%2Fpasswd&add=kitty31.gif
```

See it? That's the path `/etc/passwd`, url-encoded. Oops! You may have just made your `/etc/passwd` file available for download, with a little kitty noise in the middle.

Obviously this is not a full working exploit for anything, but I trust you get the idea: The `move_uploaded_file` function makes the extra check to protect you from attacks that will inject an unintended filename into your code.

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, it doesn't secure anything while uploading, but it helps you to prevent security holes when displaying the image by not uploading it at the first place? (and also that's only if you made a bad coding there) And how does it know it's a bad file name? if there is a urlencoded slash in it?

Comment: No, not quite. After you-the-user upload an image, you will continue to send requests to tell the server how to edit it, and then to send it back to you. These later requests can be tweaked to trick the server into sending you something you didn't actually upload. You (@HtmHell) are right that correctly written code could work safely without need of this feature, but that still leaves **a lot** of code that can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

The security issue in this case is the upload directory will be visible to public.

To avoid this case, you need to configure your web server such as Apache to make the directory forbidden to public.

Also, whenever you upload file through PHP script, rename files with mixed characters.

For example, you could use encrypted timestamps combined with actual file name.

It seems to be conventional to handle file uploads. You could stick with this way to handle file uploads securely.

**EDITED:**

This answer is edited as per your question in the comment.

You need to have an existing file within any of your www directory to rename it with `rename($existing_old_file_name, $new_file_name)` function.

`move_uploaded_file($tmp_uploaded_file_name, $new_file_name)` function moves the uploaded file from the tmp directory to the destination you specify as a second parameter in the function.

Comment: But you also have those issues when using `move_uploaded_file`. My question is why `move_uploaded_file` and not `rename`?

Comment: You need to have an existing file within your www directories to rename it with `rename()` function. `move_uploaded_file()` function moves the uploaded file from the tmp directory to the destination you specified as a second parameter in the function.

Comment: No, with `rename` you can also move a file from the temp directory to the destination folder like so: `rename($tmp_uploaded_file_name, $new_file_name)`

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, `rename()` function doesn't upload image files correctly and also, you will need to specify absolute tmp directory with the uploaded tmp file name as the source in the first parameter in the function, destination can be absolute and relative as well.